# 3g connection on android emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, 3g

I am trying out this sample application in http://android-er.blogspot.com/2012/03/search-woeid-from-httpqueryyahooapiscom.html.

Previously when I was trying out other sample app, I was able to access google map and internet.

However, I am not sure what is causing my 3g connection in the android emulator to show an X now.

In the emulator, I have also checked Settings-Mobile Networks-Data enabled-ticked.

In the manifest file, I have put in this " " .

I even reinstalled my Eclipese and Android SDK to see if it helps.

I am currently using Eclipse Version: 3.7.2 and Android SDK 4.03

Can someone advise me what can I do to connect to 3g in the emulator?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried pressing F8 while the emulator is open? It should toggle the networking on/off ( http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html#KeyMapping).

If that doesn't work, maybe you can try logging into the emulator shell with "adb shell" from the command line and pinging a website to get more clues into the error.