# I'm not able to connect to the internet on the Android Emulator in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-emulator

This question is regarding Android Studio. I just learned some basic Android through a course. So, while I was tinkering around in a Test Application, I discovered the code to connect to a website. Eg. Facebook, Youtube.

I've linked the code correctly to the button, but I'll still give you the code that I tried to create.

```
public void browsefacebook (View v){
    Intent browseFb = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("https://www.facebook.com"));
            startActivity(browseFb);
```

So, that's basically the code that I made. I've selected the permissions correctly, but every time I tap the button to connect to Facebook or YouTube. It crashes on me. It says, "Unfortunately, TestOne has stopped." Now, if you ask me if I have added the user permissions, I have added them. The only strange thing that I notice on the Android Emulator is that **the 3G sign in the notification bar has an X on it.** So, I'm guessing that's the problem, I'd really appreciate if anyone could help me resolve the issue.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the crash logs?

Answer (score 0):

Try pressing `F8` while in the emulator.

Source: [3g connection on android emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10766377/3g-connection-on-android-emulator)

Comment: I tried that, but it didn't work. The 3G symbol just disappears. If I press it again, the 3G symbol comes but it has an 'X' on where the network strength is supposed to show.